# Can you capture or silence errors when reading a file with $(< file)?

Tags: zsh

I can read a file in zsh with `$(< file)`; for example:

```
% print 'Hello, world!' > test
% x=$(< test); print $x
Hello, world!
```

However, errors are printed to stderr; for example:

```
% x=$(< doesnt-exist); print $x
zsh: no such file or directory: doesnt-exist

# The actual error in my script, for posterity.
% x=$(< /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/temp2_input); print $x
zsh: error when reading /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/temp2_input: no such device or address
```

Is there any way to capture or silence this error? You can test for readability or use `cat 2>&1` and checking the exit code (which is what I used for now), but I wonder if `$(< file)` can be used too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect in the normal way even when doing a variable assignment.

```
x=$(< doesnt-exist) 2>/dev/null ; print -r -- $x
```

That should be silent.

Comment: `$(< doesnt-exist) 2>/dev/null)` also seems to work; is there a difference? 